# Maven download unspecified jar file in pom

Tags: jakarta-ee, jar, maven-2

I am using maven as project dependency management tool. I have project where I put xml file in maven with specific version but I downloaded the older version also.

Here I want to download `spring-core 5.0.8` via this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

It also downloads the `3.0.6.RELEASE` version of spring-core. How to skip this dependency? , this is my old pom, this also downloads the 3.0.6.

here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.guru.gurusahakari</groupId>
<artifactId>gurusahakari</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>



<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <tomee.version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</tomee.version>
    <version.shrinkwrap.resolver>2.0.0</version.shrinkwrap.resolver>
    <javaassist.version>3.21.0-GA</javaassist.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>apache-m2-snapshot</id>
        <name>Apache Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <!-- <finalName>gurusahakari</finalName> -->
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-test-libs</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                                <version>1.2</version>
                            </artifactItem>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
                                <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
                                <version>1.1.2</version>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.directory}/test-libs
                        </outputDirectory>
                        <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks> <!-- otherwise openejb embedded and tomee embedded shares the same context 
                    and EJBContainer is broken -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <configuration>
                    <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.aries.blueprint</groupId>
            <artifactId>blueprint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanPaths>
                    <scanPath>org.opendaylight</scanPath>
                </scanPaths>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825386/blueprint-maven-plugin-runtimeexception -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xbean-finder-shaded</artifactId>
                    <version>4.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>blueprint-generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.openejb.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <tomeeClassifier>plus</tomeeClassifier>
                <args>-Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=256m</args>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- validation jar -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.bval/bval-jsr303 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.bval</groupId>
        <artifactId>bval-jsr303</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.session/spring-session -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj/saaj-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jackson data biending -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

here is the result of mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=spring-core.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.guru.gurusahakari:gurusahakari:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: junit:junit:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 3.8.1 @ line 284, column 15
[WARNING]  
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
 [WARNING] 
 [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
 [WARNING] 
  [INFO]                                                                         
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Building gurusahakari 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ gurusahakari ---
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Total time: 5.987 s
   [INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-15T09:59:09+05:45
    [INFO] Final Memory: 11M/158M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: No chance for this

Comment: apparently, yes i was confuse too. May be other process trigger the download

Comment: But it won't affect your project compilation right?

Comment: Sure. Also, i am not interested in compilation.

Comment: Which version is showing as used when you run `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: @DanielScott Here is my dependency tree. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692397/tomee-caused-by-java-lang-runtimeexception-at-org-apache-xbean-asm5-methodvi . Also it show jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile

Comment: parlad I created a pom.xml with the content above, but since I don't have any other project file I added the plugin configuration below to avoid web.xml complain. But after that I couldn't reproduce: <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <configuration>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

Answer (score 5):

In order to be more assertive I would need to take a look at your pom.xml.

But there is an oficial way to deal with situations like this. Just add a tag like the following in your pom:

```
<!-- Your actual dependencies -->
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!-- Constraints you put on your direct and transitive dependencies -->
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

This will override the dependencies to use this specific version.

Comment: now , there is no jar file inside maven . Do you knew what cause this?

Comment: and error all over  the project. it is not accepting autowire and controller etc annotations.

Comment: looks like dependency inside , `<dependencyManagement></dependencyManagement>`  can not be imported. It gives the error while moving into `<dependencyManagement></dependencyManagement>`.

Comment: Dear Parlad, I forgot to include the correct tag dependencyManagement -> dependencies -> dependency.

the problem you are facing is probably because you have one or more dependencies that have dependency in different versions of spring.

the best aproach would be to rebuild all dependencies using the same version of spring.

you might also try the mvn dependency:tree that prints all dependency hierarchy.

Comment: i already put that way , here pom does not give any error but , the jar file seems empty and case error all over the projec

Comment: If you share your pom.xml I can try to help you sort this out.

Comment: @Alesandro, i have updated the question. Can you please suggest.

Comment: @parladneupane dependencies in `<dependencyManagement>` does not constitute actual dependency on the artifact. That means you have to include the dependency in both **a)** your `<dependencies>` list and **b)** `<dependencyManagement>`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to understand why the 3.0.6 version of spring-core is getting pulled down.

Possibly, there is some transitive dependency on it - see if you can find it with:
`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=spring-core`

once you have found it, you can use Dependency Exclusions to prevent it from being downloaded, see this:
[Dependency Exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>${xyz.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

where xyz is the artifact with the transitive dependency on the old spring version.

Comment: should i suppose to add <optional>false</optional> here for spring core 4.3.8?

Comment: not sure you need that, see the example I put in the post - did you find a transitive dependency on 3.0.6 ?

Comment: not , actually . i posted mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=spring-cor result. I did not see any specific.

Answer (score 0):

The easy  way you can solve these kind of problems is to use a graphical tool like eclipse.(i.e)

- Open the project with [Eclipse for java](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).
- Select the pom.xml.

[image]

- Open the tap of dependency management.

[image]

- Filter, analyze and inspect the dependencies don't apply

[image: Dependency Management]

- Remove the dependencies you don't want.

[image]

It will save you lot of google searches and time.

Answer (score 0):

I had gotten this error multiple times during development. 
I fixed it by downloading the jar and adding externally, which are described below.

Steps:

1. you search "*.jar maven dependency" on google or directly head over to maven dependency website and search for the jar  ( replace * with your required jar name )
2. Download the jar from maven dependency
3. Right Click project and click on properties
4. Select "Java Build Path" on the left, and then the "Libraries" tab. Now, click the "Add External JARS..." button
5. Locate and select the jar files that you downloaded, and then click "Open"
6. Finally, click "OK" to close the dialog box. You will know that everything went ok if, when you open your project folder, you see an item called "Referenced Libraries", and upon expanding this item, you see your jar files listed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try like this
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
it should work fine
```

Comment: be specific with version and also it should be the latest one will solve most of the problems

Comment: He can't remove something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I had some weird situations with Maven similar to this and I solved it deleting the repository folder (%user-folder%/.m2/repository) and perform a `clean install` again. Sometimes previous versions of the your project artifacts with wrong or outdated pom.xml files can result in unwanted behaviours with maven dependency resolution.

If you are using an IDE like IntelliJ IDEA (maybe Eclipse works like this as well) keep in mind that it maintains its own artifacts cache. So you also could try to do a `clean install` from command prompt to discard things.